# Optimising JavaScript for an exercise on Codewars

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I'm currently working on my JavaScript by doing exercises on Codewars.com.
I've been doing OK but I've come across this question and I can't figure out a way to optimize it.
Here is the question:

**Sum of Pairs**

*Given a list of integers and a single sum value, return the first two values (parse from the left please) in order of appearance that add up to form the sum.*

```
sum_pairs([0, 0, -2, 3], 2)
#  there are no pairs of values that can be added to produce 2.
== None/nil/undefined (Based on the language)

sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5],         10)
#              ^-----------^   5 + 5 = 10, indices: 1, 5
#                    ^--^      3 + 7 = 10, indices: 3, 4 *
#  * entire pair is earlier, and therefore is the correct answer
== [3, 7]
```

**NOTE:** *There will also be lists tested of lengths upwards of 10,000,000 elements. Be sure your code doesn't time out.*

---

It's simple enough and my solution works, but times out after 12 seconds on the 10,000,000 elements test.

My solution:

```
function sum_pairs(numArray, num){
  var nums = numArray;
  var sum = num;
  var resultsArray = [];
  var result;

  for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    for(var j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++){
      if(nums[i] + nums[j] == sum){
        resultsArray.push({resArray: [nums[i],nums[j]], weight: j});
      }
    }
  }

  if(resultsArray.length != 0){
  var result = resultsArray.pop();
    for(var i = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++){
      if(result.weight > resultsArray[i].weight){
        result = resultsArray[i];
      }
    }
    result = result.resArray;
  }

  return result;

}
```

---

Question:

How to optimize this code so that it doesn't time out.
I'm just a beginner programming wise and I'm unsure what part(s) of my solution causes slowdown.
I'm about to read up on Big O notation now, any other resources for learning about code optimization?

Comment: Good question, but this is probably better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll do this, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example `[a,b,c,d,e]`

Instead of taking `a` and testing against the right side (`b,c,d,e`)

```
[a,b,c,d,e]
 i j j j j
   i j j j
     i j j
       i j
```

Start at `b` and test against the left side (`a`)

```
[a,b,c,d,e]
 j i
 j j i
 j j j i
 j j j j i
```

This way the first match you find is the one you want, and you can return without having to loop through the whole array.

Comment: Changed the solution to this:
    `function sum_pairs(numArray, num){
}`

Comment: Sorry my formating was off and then I ran out of editing time ><
My code looks like this now:

`function sum_pairs(numArray, num){
 var nums = numArray;
 var sum = num;
 var resultsArray = [];

 for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < i; j++){
       if(nums[i] + nums[j] == sum){
          return [nums[j], nums[i]];
       } 
    }
  }
}

`

Still doesn't run fast enough!!
Thanks for the suggestion though.
Pissed off with this question now but I really want to solve it!

Comment: Very new to stack overflow, struggling with the formatting in the comments. Seems to be handled very differently...

Have to look up how to add new lines...

Comment: @user2831946 I dont think you can add new lines in comments, and too bad the change wasn't enough :S